# Is protractor.findElement() meant to scroll to that element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

My current unit test (protractor + angularJS project) is failing with the error `UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (525, 1103)`. I used debugger to stop it just before failure, and the only reason I can think that it would fail is because the button is not in the view port (you would have to scroll down).

The failing lines are

```
homeLink = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.linkText('Home'));
homeLink.click();
expect(ptor.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(homeUrl);
```

From https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/319, he says *'...when i use findElement() it will scroll them to the "top" of the page'*. And the comments agree.

In my test `homeLink = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.linkText('Home'));` is not causing the the page to scroll.

Am I wrong in thinking it should?

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 9):

You need to scroll down (or maximize browser if this allows you to see the button you would like to click on) first so that the button is visible on the page:

```
var scrollIntoView = function () {
    arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
}
browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, yourwebelement);
```

Comment: So does that mean findElement() doesn't autoscroll to the element? If not, what are they talking about in github link?

Comment: Only Supported in IE and Firefox    https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Read-write_capabilities

Comment: @venkat This code snippet is running javascript inside the browser, so it should be supported in any browser which supports [Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), which includes all major browsers (incl. IE6+).

Comment: I am getting Failed: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using it.

Comment: If you use this method, the "yourwebelement" in this case is the web element from protractor. if you have a protractor element, you need to call the .getWebElement() function on it.

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to get the webElement browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ed.getWebElement());